# TensorFlow ValueError: At least two variables have the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am stuck with saving the trained model session using TensorFlow's `saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder`.

When I run:

```py
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(model_path)

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    model._sess, [tf.saved_model.SERVING],
    signature_def_map={
        'predict_images':
        tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs={'total': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.x)},
            outputs={'target': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.y)},
            method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME) ,
    },
    main_op=tf.tables_initializer(),
    strip_default_attrs=True)

builder.save()
```

I get an error complaining:

```py
File "lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/builder_impl.py", line 585, in add_meta_graph_and_variables
  saver = self._maybe_create_saver(saver)
..blahblah..
ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: first_compression_layer/dense/bias
```

I get same error when I use *tf.saved_model.simple_save()* as well.

More interesting thing about this error is that when I try to list up all variables in the graph:

```py
for variable in [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node if n.name.startswith("first_compression_layer/dense/bias")]:
    print(variable)
```

I get unique variable names.:

```
first_compression_layer/dense/bias/Initializer/zeros
first_compression_layer/dense/bias
first_compression_layer/dense/bias/Assign
first_compression_layer/dense/bias/read
first_compression_layer/dense/bias/Initializer/zeros_1
first_compression_layer/dense/bias_1
first_compression_layer/dense/bias/Assign_1
first_compression_layer/dense/bias/read_1
```

I am using tensorflow  1.14.0

Comment: Saving empty model without ```builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables``` works fine.

Comment: Is that the only code you are running? I usually get this error when I try to load two graphs (one after another) without clearing the default graph. Besides that I can't see an error here except that espressos are way better.

Comment: @carobnodrvo
I suspected same as you since the code is running in a loop, but I am getting this error in the first iteration. (-> Can this still cause problem?)
Sounds weird but, I have a couple of reasons for doing this.

Comment: I think so. Can't find it right now but if you try, I am sure that you can find a lot of bug reports where TF doesn't clean up graphs properly, especially if you create/manage them in a loop. Does it work if you remove the loop? You could also try `reset_default_graph()`.